# mPDF very heavy file after import one page from external pdf

Tags: php, file, pdf, import, mpdf

I import external pdf file and try tuuse only first page of it but weight of new pdf is as heavy as full pdf , and is only containing first page when external file contain like 200 pages .

Any idea why , or is maybe some sort of clear command to drop rest of pages from memory of new pdf ??

my code is very simple:

```
$pdfp = new mPDF('utf-8','A4-L');
$pdfp->displayDefaultOrientation = true;
$pdfp->SetImportUse();
$pagecount = $pdfp->SetSourceFile('ORGINAL.PDF');

///// first page only
$import_page = $pdfp->ImportPage(1);
$pdfp->UseTemplate($import_page);

$pdfp->Output('firstpageonly.pdf', 'F');
```

any idea , please :)

Regards
Hubert

Comment: There are PDFs which use shared resource dictionaries for all pages. In such a case importing one page usually includes the resources of all pages. Resources are bitmap images, form xobjects, patterns, fonts, etc etc. Your PDF might be such a case.

Comment: Thank you for comment 

is there any command to remove them all ?? I in my situation I need only first page and anyway I will convert it to the picture but because pdf is so big ImageMagick in php can not convert first page directly to jpg so I thought keep only first page in to new pdf and then convert , but is look like is more complicated !:(

Or maybe mPDF have option to export individual page to bitmap ???

Comment: *is there any command to remove them all ?* - well, you don't want to remove them all because after removing all resources, your pdf cannot display anything but vector graphics. You want to give each page its own resource dictionary containing only those resources the page needs. Unfortunately I don't know mpdf and in particular not whether it offers a function for that, I only have an idea how I would implement such a feature using pdf libraries I know (which happen to be for java or .net). But maybe knowing this required task allows you to find some solution somewhere.